# How to format the placeholder of html textarea element

Tags: css, textarea

I want to make placeholder formatted as attached.
The full content of placeholder is: "I will do something I really good at". In which, "I will" is font-weight bold, the rest is normal.

I don't have any idea how to do this. Can anyone please give me a solution. Thank you.

[image]

Comment: You can't do that using pure CSS. Look into using a label and formatting that. And think about whether the text you are proposing really is  placeholder - look up what a placeholder is supposed to be used for (a hint or example of what the user should type). Yours looks more like a label - it's not exactly an example of what you want them to type.

Answer (score 0):

I think the first two words are text inside of the `textarea` tag.
You could use a `div` with `contenteditable` attribute and manipulate it using `::before` and some `JavaScript`.
This is an example and you can modify it as you wish:

```js
const div = document.querySelector('div')
div.oninput = ()=>{
 div.classList.remove('bg')
}
```

```css
div{
  background:white;
  border:1px solid green;
  padding:5px;
  cursor:text;
  width:300px;
  min-height:200px;
}
.bg::before{
  content:"do someting I'm really good at";
  color:gray;
  position:absolute;
  margin-left:50px;
}
```

```html
<div class='bg' contenteditable>
  I will&nbsp; 
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

***Hi,***

I think there is a solution, but it's a bit tricky. As far as I know with pure CSS we can't change the `font-weight` for just a part of placeholder text, but we can play a little bit with text color.

---

### Solution

We can use the background settings to only appear for the text and set the text color transparent. In short that give us the text with the content (color) of the background.

To achieve the effect of getting only a piece of text in a different color, we can apply a linear gradient to our background. The negative trait of this solution is that we need to calculate/match how much of text want in another color, but in your case when the placeholder text (and it's design) is static we can set that once for this specific element and should be good.

I prepared a short code snippet with descripted idea below:

```css
::placeholder {
  background-image: linear-gradient(90deg, black 13%, gray 13%);
  background-clip: text;
  color: transparent;
  /* In most browsers, the placeholder text is grey through opacity, so we disable it's transparency. */
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<textarea name="vanminhquangtriTextarea" rows="5" cols="50" placeholder="I will do something I really good at"></textarea>
```

---

### Knowledge

You can read more about creating multicolor text using element background e.g. [on this webside](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/css/how-to-create-a-multicolor-text-in-html-and-css.html), it's nicley explained in my opinion.

The source of information about CSS properties can be for example *W3Schools*:

- [CSS background property](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background.php)
- [CSS Gradients](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp)
- [CSS ::placeholder selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_placeholder.php)

---

I hope it meets your requirements, because in this solution, the whole text has the same font weight, and only the colors of individual parts of the text have changed.

***Cheers***